# Compiler error for signedness in C

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

I am relatively new to C and after compiling a program, which does run and work, I received a few compiler warnings.

A warning says that:

```
main.c: In function ‘lsh_read_line’:
main.c:65:2: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 2 of ‘getline’ differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
    getline(&line, &bufsize, stdin);
    ^
```

```c
char *lsh_read_line(void)
{
    char *line = NULL;
    ssize_t bufsize = 0;
    getline(&line, &bufsize, stdin);
    return line;
}
```

Most of the solutions I have seen suggested using pointers when allocating buffer space, but I am just letting getline allocate the memory itself so I am not sure how to correct this.

Also, I think this warning is related but I have no idea what it means or how to correct it:

```
In file included from main.c:4:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:678:20: note: expected ‘size_t * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘ssize_t *’
 extern _IO_ssize_t getline (char **__restrict __lineptr,
                    ^
```

Comment: is there any reason for not using the correct type (size_t) ?

Comment: Upvoted for trying to solve warnings even if the program "runs fine".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssize_t` and `size_t` are different types. `size_t` is the unsigned integer type that is the return type of `sizeof` and the argument type of `*alloc`, `fread/fwrite` and such functions; `size_t` is defined in C standard.

`ssize_t` on the other hand is a *signed* integer type. It is not part of C standard, but it is used in POSIX as a return type of functions that return for example number of bytes written/read, or negative value on error.

You shouldn't confuse these 2 types with each other. Note `getline` returns `ssize_t` but takes a pointer to `size_t`:

```
ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
```

`getline` *returns* the number of characters read, but `*n` will contain the number of bytes allocated for the buffer. The return value is of type `ssize_t` - a signed integer - so that on error `-1` can be returned. On the other hand, `size_t` is the argument type of `*alloc` functions; and the decumentation says that `*n` shall point to the existing size of memory allocation of `*lineptr` if `*lineptr` is non-null.

Thus

```
char *lsh_read_line(void)
{
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t bufsize;
    ssize_t n_read = getline(&line, &bufsize, stdin);
    if (n_read < 0) {
        // handle error condition?
        // then maybe:
        return NULL;
    }
    return line;
}
```

---

While some people claim that that they're "just" warnings but the truth about the C compiler warnings often is that they can be grave errors in some cases, and cause your program to have undefined behaviour

Comment: Thanks for the help! This definitely improved my understanding of getline.

Comment: Also if you can, you should reuse the memory allocated (for that you need to keep track of the `size_t n`, it helps avoiding heap fragmentation.

Answer (score 1):

The errors says it is expecting a `size_t*` instead of a `ssize_t*`

Try changing `ssize_t bufsize = 0;` to `size_t bufsize = 0;`